# Style Input Placeholder R

Tags: ios, react-native

Is it possible to style an inputs placeholder on React Native. This is an Input.

```
 <TextInput style={styles.input}
            onChangeText={(password) => this.setState({password})}
            value={this.state.password}
            placeholder='Password'
            secureTextEntry={true}/>
```

How would I define `styles.input` to edit the placeholder's text color?

On css, a vendor prefixer is needed.

Comment: It's currently only possible to define `placeholderTextColor` as a property for `<TextInput>`. Is that enough?

Answer (score 1):

On **TextInput** documentation there is a prop called **placeholderTextColor**. The way you implement this property is in the following way:

```
<TextInput style={styles.input}
        onChangeText={(password) => this.setState({password})}
        value={this.state.password}
        placeholder='Password'
        placeholderTextColor'#COLORHERE'
        secureTextEntry={true}/>
```

Only brief into the documentation when implementing it first but React Native's docs cover a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I have it, inside my same .js file:

```
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    description: {
      marginBottom: 20,
      fontSize: 18,
      textAlign: 'center',
      color: '#656565'
    }
    image: {
      width: 217,
      height: 138
    },
    input: {
    // your style
    }
});
```

Comment: Looks good but the question asks for styling the placeholder attribute.

Comment: "How would I define styles.input ?"  <-- Isn't that the question?

Comment: "Is it possible to style an inputs placeholder on React Native." Ill edit the question to make it clearer